# "find out more..." link for civievents points to a page that does not exists

Tags: civievent, wordpress

I'm running civicrm 4.6.5 in WordPress 4.2.4. I'm using civievents to manage multiple events and would like to display these events on a WordPress Page.

I'm using the following short codes on the events page. 
[civicrm component="event" id="17" action="info" mode="live" hijack="0"]
[civicrm component="event" id="18" action="info" mode="live" hijack="0"]

And they appear like this: https://lofcenter.org/events/
[image: civievents listed in a WP page]
**But when I click on either event to "find out more..."** it points to https://lofcenter.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&reset=1&id=17
**and gets the following error:**
[image: sorry no posts match your criteria] 
Am i missing a configuration option?
btw - I'm not running any Cache on this installation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those paths look correct, but they depend upon a page existing at the path /civicrm.  CiviCRM 4.6 creates one upon install, but maybe you renamed or removed it not knowing what it was for.

**The simplest solution is to create a blank page called CiviCRM that has the URL https://lofcenter.org/civicrm**

CiviCRM on WordPress takes a page, wipes the content, and sticks the CiviCRM content there when the "page=CiviCRM" parameter is set.  The page it uses is whatever's before the question mark in the URL, and you can set it in Administer > System Settings > CMS Database Integration.  However, any working page or post will do, so just to demonstrate, the link https://lofcenter.org/aboutus/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&reset=1&id=17 works just fine.  You just need to make sure the page CiviCRM points to exists, so you can either set the base page to an existing page or create a base page where CiviCRM expects one should be.

Comment: That was a cool example Andrew. Yes, your answer fixed the problem. I created the page /civicrm and now events are viewable.